# Resultset from jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, functions, jsonb

I have a function that build a JSONB array of object.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  RETURNS TABLE(field1 INT, field2 TEXT)
```

In DECLARE part:

```
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
    d JSONB;
    d_list JSONB[];
    ...
```

Then, I loop on a query result to build a `d` JSON object

```
FOR r IN
    SELECT ........

LOOP    
    d = jsonb_build_object('field1', r.foo, 'field2', r.bar);
    d_list = d_list || d;
END LOOP;
```

And I want to return a recordset of `d_list`

```
RETURN QUERY (
  select * from jsonb_to_recordset(d_list) as x(field1 int, field2 text)  
);
```

This does not work because `jsonb_to_recordset` cannot handle JSONB[]

How can I achieve that ? I read about UNNEST() but I don't understand how to use it in this case.

Comment: That doesn't look like you need a loop or even PL/pgSQL but without seeing the complete code this is impossible to answer.

Comment: `jsonb[]` is not a JSON array it's an array of JSON. As it is a "native" array you need to use [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) to work with it, not JSON function. In this case you need `unnest()` to turn array elements into rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I created a snippet with a part of the function
https://gist.github.com/ceadreak/eeb9594af3a17e1d18c7281a17fdf2fe

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as you can see in the snippet, the expected result should be a table containing data for each jsonb objects in the array. Any idea of how to achieve that ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion with JSON array (type `json` or `jsonb`) versus Postgres array of JSON (type `json[]` or `jsonb[]`) is a **red herring** in your case. Looking at the [query you disclosed](https://gist.github.com/ceadreak/eeb9594af3a17e1d18c7281a17fdf2fe) in a later comment, all of this is pointless complication. There is no need to involve JSON at all, nor all the casting and concatenation, nor even a loop.

Radically simplify to a plain SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_deals(_deals_count int DEFAULT 6)
  RETURNS TABLE(target_id int, target_type text, weight int)
  LANGUAGE sql ROWS 10 AS
$func$
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER  BY random())::int  AS rn  -- returned as weight!
FROM  (
   (
   SELECT p.id AS target_id, 'product' AS target_type
   FROM   products p
   JOIN   products_configurations pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
   JOIN   content_products        cp ON p.id = cp.product_id
   WHERE  pc.deleted_at IS NULL
   AND    (pc.status & 1) = 0    -- faster than the cast you had
   AND    (cp.status & 16) = 16  -- published
   AND    (p.status & 3) = 3     -- active and available
   AND    p.recommendation_rate = 3
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  10
   )
   UNION
   (
   SELECT d.id, 'discount'
   FROM   discounts                d
   JOIN   discounts_configurations dc ON d.id = dc.discount_id
   JOIN   content_discounts        cd ON d.id = cd.discount_id
   WHERE  (dc.status & 1) = 0
   AND    (cd.status & 16) = 16  -- published
   AND    (d.status & 1) = 0     -- not suspended
   AND    d.recommendation_rate = 3
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  10
   )
   ) dp
ORDER  BY rn
LIMIT  _deals_count;
$func$;
```

There can be no duplicates between the two legs of the `UNION`. But the table name `products_configurations` indicates a many-to-one relationship to `products`. If so the `[INNER] JOIN` can multiply rows *within* each leg, and `UNION` is probably there to remove those duplicates. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html)

> Furthermore, it eliminates duplicate rows from its result, in the same
> way as `DISTINCT`, unless `UNION ALL` is used.

That's a very costly way of doing things. I suggest to **fix** that with [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS), which does not multiply rows, so you don't have to remove duplicates later, and a faster [**`UNION ALL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) does the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_deals(_deals_count int DEFAULT 6)
  RETURNS TABLE(target_id int, target_type text, weight int)
  LANGUAGE sql ROWS 10 AS
$func$
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER  BY random())::int  AS rn   -- returned as weight!
FROM  (
   (
   SELECT p.id AS target_id, 'product' AS target_type
   FROM   products p
   WHERE (p.status & 3) =  3        -- active and available
   AND    p.recommendation_rate = 3
   AND    EXISTS (  -- !
      SELECT FROM products_configurations pc
      WHERE  pc.product_id = p.id
      AND    pc.deleted_at IS NULL
      AND   (pc.status & 1) = 0     -- faster than the cast you had
      )
   AND    EXISTS (  -- !
      SELECT FROM content_products cp
      WHERE  cp.product_id =  p.id
      AND   (cp.status & 16) = 16   -- published
      )
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  10
   )
   UNION ALL  -- !!
   (
   SELECT d.id, 'discount'
   FROM   discounts d
   WHERE  d.recommendation_rate = 3      
   AND   (d.status  &  1) =  0      -- not suspended
   AND    EXISTS (  -- !
      SELECT FROM discounts_configurations dc
      WHERE  dc.discount_id = d.id
      AND   (dc.status &  1) =  0
      )
   AND    EXISTS (  -- !
      SELECT FROM content_discounts cd
      WHERE  cd.discount_id = d.id
      AND   (cd.status & 16) = 16  -- published
      )    
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  10
   )
   ) dp
ORDER  BY rn
LIMIT  _deals_count;
$func$;
```

At this stage, the function should be faster by orders of magnitude. (Besides actually working.)

Comment: @Erwinn Brandstetter,  Thanks for the answer. I'll check and test that today. Why do you say that 'UNION made no sense' and use UNION ALL instead ?

Comment: And what about the `contains` notion if several binary values are set ? 
e.g. `cp.status = 17` (published and another...). I have to use `(cp.status & 16)::BOOL` no ?

Comment: @ceadreak: You never need to cast for this. Especially not when *AND*ing with a power of 2 (`16 = 2^4`), where the result is either 0 or the same power of 2. To catch any matching bit for other numbers or generally, make it `(cp.status & 123) > 0`. That's really a distinct matter. Ask a new question if anything is unclear.